# Adding old-work box without making a large hole?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, light-fixture

I am changing out the vanity light, above a sink and mirror, in a bathroom.

The old light fixture had it's own wall plate screwed to the wall that the wires ran into from a hole in the drywall behind.

The new light fixture (just under 10lb in weight) requires an electrical box (as well as being a code requirement.) This house was built in 1980 and does not have an electrical box in the wall so I need to add one.

There are no studs within a few inches (the light needs to be directly above the sink) so I could use a braced box like this:

[image: braced box]

But I'd like to avoid tearing a large hole in the drywall if I can safely avoid it.

So, I'm thinking I could attach strips of plywood behind the hole to spread the weight out over a larger area and add one of these:

[image: old work box with ears]

The ears of this would rest on the plywood. This way I don't need to make a hole larger than the box.

Do you think this setup will hold a 10lb fixture (assuming the drywall is OK) or should I just rip the hole and add the braced version?

Comment: See: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/18235/36011

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one typically do "Old Work" with metal junction boxes?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26353/how-does-one-typically-do-old-work-with-metal-junction-boxes)

Comment: Adding an old-work box without making a large hole is exactly how you do old work, or you've screwed up the install and have to go with mounting a real box.

Comment: One other question that I should have asked earlier since it is not explicit in your question, does the vanity light itself screw into the wall? If so, you may not need a fixture-rated electrical box.

Answer (score 2):

The braced versions are designed to be installed through the same 4" hole that you'd use for the blue 'old-work' box. I wouldn't trust a 10lb light fitting to be kept up only by the strength of drywall - especially in a damp environment like a bathroom.

Comment: I couldn't put the screws into the brace ends without pulling out more of the drywall. I've seen the "twist" braces that expand and will fit through the same hole, but without knowing exactly what's run behind the wall (e.g. a vent pipe, or more electrical wiring) I wouldn't want to use those.

Comment: [Octagon Box with Old Work Clips](http://www.garvinindustries.com/electrical-junction-boxes/3-1-2-and-4-octagon-junction-boxes/4-octagon-cut-in/54151-owbx)

Comment: @rin-tin-tin After you cut the hole for the box, you should be able to probe before you twist it into place. The camera on your cell phone works wonders for seeing into tight spaces.

Comment: @statueuphemism I hadn't though of that

Comment: @Mazura Where does the box you linked [(Octagon Box with Old Work Clips)](http://www.garvinindustries.com/electrical-junction-boxes/3-1-2-and-4-octagon-junction-boxes/4-octagon-cut-in/54151-owbx) indicate it is rated for any sort of lighting fixture support? My understanding is that it has to be listed for lighting fixture support (50 lbs of lighting fixture support implicitly) or be explicitly marked on the box per 314.27(A)(2).

Comment: 2014 NEC reference: 314.27 Outlet Boxes; (A) Boxes at Luminaire or Lampholder Outlets; (2) Ceiling Outlets. At every outlet used exclusively for lighting, the box shall be designed or installed so that a luminaire or lampholder may be attached. Boxes shall be required to support a luminaire weighing a minimum of 23 kg (50 lb). A luminaire that weighs more than 23 kg (50 lb) shall be supported independently of the outlet box, unless the outlet box is listed and marked on the interior of the box to indicate the maximum weight the box shall be permitted to support.

Comment: @statueuphemism - Isn't that what "fixture rated" means? Page 33: [cooperindustries.com pdf](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/crousehinds/commercial-products/catalog-pdfs/cp-catalog-outlet-box-section.pdf)

Comment: @statueuphemism If I should find something that prevents the twist brace, either because it's too large or wire is running along the stud, is there something else that's acceptable (and safe)?

Comment: @Mazura That is what fixture rated means. While one of the boxes page 33 of your link has ears, it does not have any integral old work clips, but rather has screw/nail holes. I have no doubt that it could secure the box if secured with appropriate screws/nails. However, my understanding is that if you add old work clips, it potentially invalidates its fixture rating.

Comment: @rin-tin-tin - That was the conclusion I jumped to and why I suggested a *metal* old work octagon box. I've no idea what that plastic stuff is rated for. | (at) Statue - That's why I linked to a picture of one that does have both.

Comment: @Mazura For your first link with both plaster ears and old work clips, I can find no indication of any sort of fixture support listing and I highly doubt that the box with both can rest on drywall and hold up a static load of 50 lbs from the ceiling as required if unmarked and UL listed for luminaire fixture support.

Comment: @rin-tin-tin I haven't done a lot of shopping in this area since the twist-in-place braces have met my needs for old work, so I haven't come across many other products. Some quick googling doesn't seem to turn up any other ideas that I can confidently say would work for your situation.

Comment: @statueuphemism - This is on a wall and less than 10 pounds. You're not supposed to do pull-ups on it. The pdf: "3 1/4” OCTAGON OUTLET BOXES† – 9.0 CUBIC INCH CAPACITY 1 1/2” DEEP **FIXTURE RATED** UL LISTED"

Comment: @Mazura You're confusing the listings for two products. The cooper industries listing you're citing is screw-in/nail-on (no old work clips) and is fixture rated. The garvin industries product with old work clips does not cite a fixture rating that I can find. Also, thank you for pointing out that this is a wall-mounted, don't know how my brain misread it as ceiling mounted. Similar restrictions apply (314.27(A)(1)), however it appears that there is an additional allowance for extension rings or other box similar box-mounted fixtures.

Comment: 2014 NEC reference: 314.27(A)(1) Vertical Surface Outlets. Boxes used at luminaire or lampholder outlets in or on a vertical surface shall be identified and marked on the interior of the box to indicate the maximum weight of the luminaire that is permitted to be supported by the box, if other than 23 kg (50 lb).

Comment: 2014 NEC 314.27(A)(1) reference continued: *Exception: A vertically mounted luminaire or lampholder weighing not more than 3 kg (6 lb) shall be permitted to be supported on other boxes or plaster rings that are secured to other boxes, provided that the luminaire or its supporting yoke, or the lampholder, is secured to the box with no fewer than two No. 6 or larger screws.*

Comment: @statueuphemism  and Mazura Thanks guys. Yes, it's a wall fixture. I saw some old-work boxes "rated" for 10lb, but because the fixture is almost 10lb I didn't want to trust it by itself. Hence I would support it with plywood to spread the load. But I'll try the brace method first.